# domain.com redirects to www.domain.com

Tags: apache-2.2

have just moved to a dedicated server.. but why can it be that domain.com redirects to www.domain.com?

I haven't done any mod_rewrite yet?!

webserver: apache 2.2

what could be the cause?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The dns server also only have one A record

```
* (wildcard) A 0.0.0.0 (ip)
```

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome ?

Comment: what kind of website do you host on that server? Maybe it does that redirection itself via javascript or http-forward.

Comment: @wulluxz.. no because I have replace all content on index.php with <?echo 'test';exit;?>

Comment: hmm.. I have tested it in FF but when testing in IE there are no problems? is there some kind of cache I need to flush?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after sperating each part of the rewrite rules into each directory (eg /var/www/domain.com) it helped